# The $d$-skeleton of a polytope is strongly connected

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, polyhedra

A polytope is the convex hull of a finite set of points in $\mathbb R^n$. The $d$-skeleton of a polytope is the set consisting of faces of dimension at most $d$. I would like to show that every $d$-skeleton of every polytope is strongly connected, meaning that any two $d$-dimensional faces can be connected by a sequence of $d$ dimensional faces, where every two consecutive faces intersect in a dimension $d-1$ face.

For $d=1$, this is just saying that the graph of edges and vertices is connected, which seems relatively easy to prove. But what about larger $d$?

Comment: For $d = 2$, the following might possible: You have to connect two faces. For both faces, pick an edge and connect the edges via edges (corresponding to $d = 1$). Then, you follow this edge-path with adjacent faces. This might generalize (inductively) to $d > 2$.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea, but theoretically, you could have two faces that only intersect in a vertex, so you can't just follow the edges (you'd need to go through some faces in between).

Comment: Yes, if the edges of your path at a vertex are not incident to the same face, you have to follow some faces around this vertex.